# nzec error in codechef while writing code in python

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error

This code is giving Runtime error (NZEC) when I compile it in Codchef.

```
test_cases = int(raw_input())
result = 0
def output(x):
    if(x/2 >= 2):
        global result;
        result += x/2 - 1;
        output(x-2);
    else:
        print result;
        result = 0;

while(test_cases > 0):
    base = int(raw_input());
    output(base);
    test_cases = test_cases - 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NZEC error would be thrown by your code in codechef if there is any exception thrown. Input does not work like c, c++ while using python on codechef -

you can use

```
import sys
test_cases = sys.stdin.read().split()
```

Now iterate over test_cases. More info [here](https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-inputoutput)

also use `sys.stdout.write()` for outputs rather than `print`